# Unity WheelCollider falling through everything

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm building a 3D car game by using Unity 3D, there are   four wheels inside my 3d car model, I created 4 empty gameObjects , put them in the car gameobject and thier position are match with per wheel I added a wheel collider inside each of them but when I ran the game, my car fallig through the terrain. Anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

1:make sure your gameObjects is add collider with another objects
2:check your GOS position in u3d

ps: if you can show the pic on your question , that would be good for your question!!

Comment: yes , ofcourse I've added wheelCollider with another gameObject not the same with the Wheel,I'm new in Unity so, what is the GOS position?